# Determining when a view created programmatically did appear on screen

Tags: swift, uiview

I have a textField which, when tapped, pops up a vertical stackView created programatically. The stackView is a child of the textField. `textField.addSubview(stackView)` places the stackView's origin at the textField's origin. I wish to move the stackView's origin up vertically by an amount equal to the height of the stackView. If I do:

```
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        stackView = UIStackView()  // var stackView: UIStackView!
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .leading
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.spacing = 0
        stackView.backgroundColor = .white
        stackView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        stackView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

        for title in titleList {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(createButton(title))
        }

        textField.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -stackView.frame.height)
    }
```

It doesn't work. The stackView's origin remains at the textField's origin. But if I use a constant:

```
        textField.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -144)
```

it works. I have confirmed through debugging that `stackView.frame.height` is 0 at the time the CGAffineTransform is performed. If I check its value after it has **exited** the function, I do see that its height is 144. That means the stackView hasn't actually appeared yet **within** the function.

Is there a way to catch when the programmatically-created stackView appears (sort of like the way `viewDidAppear(_:)` works) so that I can then set its position on the screen?

Comment: OK, I just now found out I can accomplish what I need by doing: `stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true`.  Even so, is there a way to determine when a programmatically-created view did appear on screen?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a canonical way to know when an individual view has appeared on screen. You might be able to hook into the `draw` method (which is hacky), but a stack view doesn't draw anything itself, so I don't think that works.

You could probably use `UIViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews`, but you might need to add the stack view to the root view for that to work.

In any case, adding the `UIStackView` as a subview of the `UITextField` is bad practice. You probably want to add it to the parent view instead. And yes, using AutoLayout is the way to go here. Let the framework handle the layout, don't try to do it using transforms.